# Lubuntu login loop and can't open command line

Tags: lubuntu

I am stuck in the Lubuntu login loop where everytime I type my password the screen flashes white and I'm back to login.

I have attempted CTRL ALT FN+F3 to login to the shell but this just sends my screen black. CTRL ALT FN+F7 will get me back to login but I cannot proceed.

Please help me!

Comment: Try this ---> Reboot, choose Advanced options for Ubuntu, Linux with ........ (recovery mode), click enable Networking one time, then root and sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop

Comment: Text logins fail?  eg. ctrl+alt+F3 will just hang?  (you mentioned FN+F3 and I'm not sure what you meant by that) How long did you wait?   Also your release of Lubuntu would help (ie. using legacy with LXDE? or modern with LXQt? )  The most command reason for GUI login failure is lack of space in $HOME (your user directory for creation of necessary work files needed by GUI) excluding graphics/driver issues (which require change by owner/user in prior session thus they'll know about it) so I'd login via text terminal & check there.  Otherwise next I'd boot a 'live' system (or runlevel 1) & look

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw

  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory

  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.